# Можно ли данный код сократить до одной строчки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
sku_ = re.search("Артикул товара: (\d+)", item_info.text)
sku = sku_[1] if sku_ else ""
```

Можно ли данный код сократить до одной строчки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вариант

```
sku = sku[1] if (sku := re.search("Артикул товара:(\d+);", item_info)) else ''
```

Comment: Позволю себе добавить, что данное решение будет актуально для версий python 3.8 и выше

Answer (score 3):

У меня так получилось, но наверняка можно ещё лучше сделать:

```py
sku = (re.search("Артикул товара: (\d+)", item_info.text) or ('',''))[1]
```

Comment: Если индекс от конца сделать (`[-1]`), то можно после `or` записать список из одного элемента, получится немного короче (хотя это уже код-гольфом попахивает): `sku = (re.search("Артикул товара: (\d+)", item_info.text) or [""])[-1]`

Answer (score 3):

Кое-кто считает оператор `:=` некрасивым. Кто-то полагает что оператор `or` нехорошо применять к не булевым значениям. Обойдёмся без некрасивых и нехороших вещей с помощью лямбды:

```
sku = (lambda m: m[1] if m else "")(re.search("Артикул товара: (\d+)", item_info.text))
```

**P.S.** Это шутка. Определённая и сразу вызванная лямбда - такой же или худший костыль как `:=` или `or`.

**P.P.S.** Механизм наподобие этого позволяет записать в одну строку вообще любое вычисление (исключения, асинхронность и т.п. отложим пока в сторону).

Answer (score 2):

Вариант решения через контейнер `Maybe` из библиотеки [`dry-python/returns`](https://github.com/dry-python/returns)

```
import re

from returns.maybe import Maybe


def get_sku(text):
    return (
        Maybe.from_optional(re.search("Артикул товара: (\d+)", text))
        .bind_optional(lambda x: x[1])  # Или .bind_optional(itemgetter(1))
        .value_or("")
    )


assert get_sku("Артикул товара: 12323423") == "12323423"
assert get_sku("sdfwefew") == ""
```

Это похоже на класс [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) из Java, но названия методов совершенно другие, и по ним сразу не угадаешь что делает каждый метод.

На Java выглядело бы примерно так:

```java
// Псевдокод
sku = Optional.ofNullable(re.search("Артикул товара: (\d+)", text))
    .map(lambda x: x[1])
    .orElse("");
```

Тут довольно очевидно, что `map` применяет функцию к непустому результату, но что делает `bind_optional` глядя на код так просто не угадаешь.

Так что скорее не рекомендую такой способ.